# How to put User E-mail in the Logger file by loggingout in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I hope you can help me with this problem.
I want to put the user email in the logger file when the user logs out every time.
How can I do that? How can I pass the user information to the logout function?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can u edit your question and add u logout function code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Symfony's way of logout customization](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-logout-customization) to get information about how to implement such behavior (***starting from Symfony 5.1***).

The process uses a `Symfony event listener`. Check the [official documentation for events and event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) for more information about how to implement this.

Comment: Thx @Thomas I will check it!